# Given a program that has both 32 and 64bit variant, how do I put them both in my PATH with different names?

Tags: windows, windows-10, terminal, cmd.exe

Take WinDbg for example. By default it installs into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\windbg.exe` (and x64), which means there are two executables with the same name.

**How can I put both of those in my path under different names, so that I can pick which one I'm launching?**

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Just use the full path to the executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to another question already answered [here](https://superuser.com/a/1129674/644647).  But, just to save you the click through.

One possible solution is to make a link (see [`mklink`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.11).aspx?)) to the files somewhere in your path and that link can have a different name.  Then you can use the name of that link to distinguish the two versions.

Example (run `cmd.exe` as an administrator - required for `mklink`):

```bat
CD /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers"

mklink windbgx86.exe x86\windbg.exe
mklink windbgx64.exe x64\windbg.exe

CD \
windbgx86.exe
windbgx64.exe
```

*(note that the example above assumes that `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers` is in your path)*

Comment: Thanks! Though it seems that your arguments are swapped, since the first argument is the link, and second argument is the source file ... so it should be `mklink windbgx86.exe x86\windbg.exe`

Comment: Doh! So, it is. I always make that mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.  (Answer has been corrected now)